# Click a link, highlight input field

Tags: hyperlink

On Techcrunch's [404 page](http://techcrunch.com/404), clicking the "a search" link highlights the search box on the top-right of the page. I was wondering how they were able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementbyId('ID').focus()">link to focus</a>
```

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?762427-Click-Link-Sets-Focus-on-Input

Has another more robust way at the bottom.